# Java - NetBeans libraries files

Tags: java, jar, project, libraries

In my Java NetBeans project I have following structure:

Project X using project Y as Library.
In project Y I use apache - commons library.
So when I am running project X I get error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils
```

Only when I pin jar file with apache commons to project X everything is working fine.

Is it possible to omit such nested imports?

Regards

**Wicia**

Comment: But is is possible to achieve this goal by modifying build.xml file?

Comment: You _could_ use [Apache Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/), which adds Maven dependency resolution to Ant. I would recommend that you simply switch build tools from Ant to Maven though - you'll reap rewards from doing so. [NetBeans support for Maven](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Maven) is excellent.